# Data centers: Looking for dataset on location, capacity, company / owner and year of establishment

Tags: uses-of-open-data

I am looking for a dataset on the location, capacity, company / owner and year of establishment for data centers (eg. of Google, Amazon, Facebook).

Any suggestiosn are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

[Data Center locations of Top Tech Companies](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/mauryansshivam/list-of-data-centers-of-top-tech-companies) is a dataset which is maintained by me on Kaggle. It contains the latitude, longitude, year of establishment etc. of top tech companies.